# Find latest entries in a NoSQL setup

Tags: php, nosql

I built a simple script in PHP which has two functions:

- Give uploaded file a UUID and timestamp, store it on disk using UUID as filename, return UUID.
- Retrieve and return stored file by UUID.

I built this without a database since the requirements were very simple, and due to policies of the client/hoster setting up a MySQL database would be tedious.

Now another requirement has come up. I need to add a function that returns a list of the X latest uploaded files, and if possible add pagination to it as well.

What's the easiest way to do this without MySQL? Or is it sufficiently difficult to warrant getting a database set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's as simple as that you can still use files. You can save timestamps in plain text file and retrieve last n rows from it. If you need something bit more complex you can try sqlite or Kyoto cabinet. Until you have a need to express relations between some sets of data, you can probably do without relational database.

Comment: Yes, I thought about writing the ids to a plain text file, but it's not random access. Finding the latest 10 from a list of 1000 would mean first skipping 990 lines. May not be an issue in practice (I don't really know what kind of traffic load to expect) but it's not really proper.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. I simply write the IDs of new uploads to a plain text file. Because each ID is exactly 37 bytes (36 + \n) the file becomes randomly accessible. I also use `flock` to make it thread-safe.

```
function gen_uuid() {
    return sprintf( '%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',
        // 32 bits for "time_low"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),

        // 16 bits for "time_mid"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ),

        // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
        // four most significant bits holds version number 4
        mt_rand( 0, 0x0fff ) | 0x4000,

        // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
        // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
        // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
        mt_rand( 0, 0x3fff ) | 0x8000,

        // 48 bits for "node"
        mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff ), mt_rand( 0, 0xffff )
    );
}

// "constants"
$savedDir = dirname(__FILE__) . '/saved';
$orderedFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/ordered.txt';

// prepare response
$resp = null;

// switch on action
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action == 'saveVideo') {

    // read params
    $video = $_REQUEST['video'];
    $face = $_REQUEST['face'];

    // add current timestamp
    $date = time();

    // generate UUID
    $id = gen_uuid();

    // package data
    $pack = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'video' => $video,
        'face' => $face,
        'date' => $date
    );

    // save package using ID as filename
    file_put_contents($savedDir . '/' . $id, json_encode($pack));

    // write new ID to file with ordered IDs
    $f = fopen($orderedFile, 'a');
    if(flock($f, LOCK_EX)) {
        fseek($f, 0, SEEK_END);
        fwrite($f, $id . "\n");
        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
    }
    fclose($f);

    $resp = array('id' => $id);


}

else if ($action == 'getLatestVideos') {

//  $debug = '';

    // parse parameters
    $amount = intval($_REQUEST['amount']);
    $start = intval($_REQUEST['start']);
//  $debug .= "amount $amount start $start";


    // find $amount latest IDs (skip $start)
    $ids = array();
    $f = fopen($orderedFile, 'r');
    if(flock($f, LOCK_SH)) {

        // get file size
        $fst = fstat($f);
        $fsize = $fst['size'];

        // determine IDs available
        $available = floor($fsize / 37);
//      $debug .= " available $available";

        if ($start < $available) {

            // determine amount to seek back
            $totamount = min($amount + $start, $available);
//          $debug .= " totamount $totamount";

            // seek back
            fseek($f, -37 * $totamount, SEEK_END);

            // now read forward until we have $amount (if could not seek back entirely, leave off the amount that would be sought back)
            for ($i = 0; $i < min($amount, $available-$start); $i++) {

                // read ID
                $id = '';
                while(strlen($id) < 36) {
                    $id .= fread($f, 36 - strlen($id));
                }

                // skip \n
                fseek($f, 1, SEEK_CUR);

                // add ID to list
                $ids[] = $id;

            }

        }

        flock($f, LOCK_UN);
    }
    fclose($f);

    // reverse IDs so list becomes from new to old
    $ids = array_reverse($ids);

    // get datas from IDs
    $resp = array();
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $resp[] = json_decode(file_get_contents($savedDir . '/' . $id));
    }

//  $resp[] = $debug;

}

else if ($action == 'getVideo') {

    // read and clean ID
    $id = strtolower($_REQUEST['id']);
    $id = preg_replace('/[^a-f0-9-]/', '', $id);

    // get data from ID
    $resp = json_decode(file_get_contents($savedDir . '/' . $id));

}

// unknown operation
else {
    $resp = 'Unknown action ' . $action;
}

// write response
echo json_encode($resp);
```